# Can't find the ADF Swing option on JDeveloper 12.1.3

Tags: swing, oracle-adf, oracle12c

Has it been removed in 12c? Can't find the ADF Swing tier. I can only use it on JDeveloper 11c.

Answer (score 2):

it is  Deprecated starting from Version: 11.1.2
but still supported, with no future enhancements as Oracle says in this URL

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/12cdeprecatedfeatures-2542989.html

you can use version 11.1.6, to build ADF Swing apps.